# Avoiding main method static definition?

Tags: java

The Person.setPhoneNumber is saying

> Main method is not static in class PersonTest, please define the main method as:
>
> ```
> public static void main(String[] args)
> ```

but I cannot define in Person class the string PersonName as static. What should I do then?

Person Class:

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String phoneNumber;

    public Person(String n, int a){
        name = n;
        age = a;
        phoneNumber = null;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public void setname(String n){
        this.name = n;
    }

    public int getAge(){
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int a){
        age = a;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber(){
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String pn){
        this.phoneNumber = pn;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Person {name=" + name +", age= " + age +", phone number =" + phoneNumber+ "}";
    }
```

}

Person Test:

```
public class PersonTest {
         public void main(String[] args){
             Person person1 = new Person("Joel.Z", 20);
             Person.setPhoneNumber("8324193601");
             Person person2 = new Person("Fred Werd", 84);
             Person.setPhoneNumber("585275333");
             System.out.println(person1);
             System.out.println(person2);
         }
 }
```

Comment: It should be `public static void main(String [] args)`

Comment: You should be doing `person1.setPhoneNumber`! The method is an instance method, not a static one!

Comment: Why do you write `Person.setPhoneNumber("585275333");`? What's the point in creating `person2` when you don't use it. And why do you try to call that method in a static manner, although it isn't static and you don't want it to be static?

Comment: Must read: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076075/learn-java/core-java-learn-java-from-the-ground-up.html

Answer (score 3):

The main method should be **`static`**:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Also, you should call you methods on an **instance**, not on a **class**:

```
public class PersonTest {
         public static void main(String[] args){
             Person person1 = new Person("Joel.Z", 20);
             person1.setPhoneNumber("8324193601");
             Person person2 = new Person("Fred Werd", 84);
             person2.setPhoneNumber("585275333");
             System.out.println(person1);
             System.out.println(person2);
         }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. Just learned about this today.

Answer (score 2):

As @ΔλЛ says is correct, your main method must be **static**, also keep in mind that you must use the instance of the created object, it means:

Here you are creating `person1` object:

```
  Person person1 = new Person("Joel.Z", 20);
```

So, you must use that object to access the attribute:

```
  person1.setPhoneNumber("8324193601");
```

instead of *Person.setPhoneNumber("8324193601");* In the same way with the second object: *person2.setPhoneNumber("585275333");* instead of *Person.setPhoneNumber("585275333");*